# Print to Network (Shared) Printer - Word Interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, interop

I need to print a *word document* on server side to a network printer. My web page sends the document and file location to the server to open and replace mail merge items and then print the document to a preferred (not default) network printer. Preferred printer name changes when document selected on web page changes

I'm using *Word 14.0 object library, Asp.Net MVC 4.0, .Net Framework 4.0, IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2*. On IIS I created an app pool that runs on an specific account Identity (accountName@DomainName). Load user profile set to true to load the network printer connections in to the registry. I allowed the Account to have permissions to run the word COM interop services. I was successful to open the document and replace the mail merge fields and save it as pdf to send the file as attachment to an email.

The word application has the default printer in its `ActivePrinter` property, so that I could print to default printer as well. But my final goal is to print the word to a preferred network printer before I close the word application and active document.

The following two Methods were causing exceptions if I try to change the `ActivePrinter` property.

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
```

**First Method:**

```
wordApp.ActivePrinter = "preferredPrinterName";
```

**Second Method;**

```
object[] oWordDialogParams = { "\\<serverName>\<PrinterName>", true };
string[] argNames = { "Printer", "DoNotSetAsSysDefault" };
object wordBasic = wordApp.WordBasic;

wordBasic.GetType().InvokeMember("FilePrintSetup"
           , System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
           , null
           , wordBasic
           , oWordDialogParams
           , null
           , null
           , argNames);
```

I found that the Word application object is not loading all the printers installed to the user account. It only loads the default printer. I'm assuming that it was the reason for exceptions when above two methods were attempting to change or add preferred printer to the application object because the printer I'm trying to set was never found in the active printers list.

How do I get all installed shared printers under user profile loaded in to the Word application object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Office interop in a server-scenario (like ASP.NET, Windows Service etc.) is NOT supported by MS - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Additionally there have been several security-related changed since Windows Vista which basically make it really hard to do anything "desktop-like" in a Windows Service (IIS/ASP.NET is just a special case of Windows Service in this regard).

Another point is "printing" from a server-scenario is likely to cause problems since IIS is a (special) Windows Service... Windows Service usually don't have a "full/real" desktop which in turn is needed for printing robustly...

I don't think that there an easy solution for your scenario...

I would break it down to different components:

- Word document handling (for example with [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx))
- Create a PDF from the resulting Word file (for example with [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx))
- Implement a HotFolder on the target network printer
- Copy the PDF over to that HotFolder for printing

This would be a robust and supported option for your scenario...

Comment: Aspose.words is awesome. No need to enable DCOM on server, it worked perfectly to print word documents to desired network printers on server side. It works for my scenario. However, Licenses are expensive. If somebody don't want to buy license for Aspose.words, I suggest enable DCOM and use service account with as limited privileges as possible to automate MS WORD with interop assemblies and save the file as PDF to the HotFolders for printing. I haven't tried for HotFolders though.